# how to make data model variable with number in c#

Tags: c#

is it possible to change name of variable to symbol or number just like bellow

```
public string Card_Nr { get; set; }
```

to be

```
public string 1275 { get; set; }
```

thanks.

Comment: Eeeehm, what? A proeprty can´t be a number. Why do you even need this? Please describe why you think that your *actual* problem - what ever this is - might be solved by this strange requirement.

Comment: There are staggeringly few scenarios in which a number would be a useful and meaningful member name; it would probably *really help* if you gave us some context as to *why* you want to name a member `1275`

Comment: couse i must tou send array models that looks like `{
      "3": "erik.selvig@example.com",
      "2": "Selvig",
      "source_id": "1234"
    },
    {
      "3": "ian.boothby@example.com",
      "2": "Boothby"
    },` and i must to send completlly model

Comment: if this was possible, what would the compiler do if you write `var 1 = 2; var x = 1;` should it set x to 1 or 2? you can try using a `Dictionary<int, string>` and serialize that to Json

Answer (score 0):

You can use a letter or _ (as Alexey said) in front of numbers.
Generally you should name variables with a name that describes it and is easy to use.